# Vim no longer calls <Plug> in insert mode?

Tags: linux, mac, vim, vim-plugins

I have the following configuration in my vimrc file.

```
inoremap <C-A> <Plug>InsertComment
```

And somewhere in my vim folder I defined

```
inoremap <silent> <Plug>InsertComment <ESC>:call INSERT_MY_COMMENT
```

The mapping worked really well after I configured it. But somehow recently it stopped functioning. And whenever I can to use the Key-bind in the insert mode, instead calling the function that I mapped, vim will just paste the entire `<Plug>InsertComment` thing to my buffer.

I tried to debug and found out that if I map

`inoremap <C-A> <ESC>:call INSERT_MY_COMMENT`

it still works as desired, which means there must be something wrong with the `<Plug>` part.

But I really have no clue on why `<Plug>` would stop being interpreted by vim as a handle to call other plugins.

I also tried to manually copy and paste

```
inoremap <silent> <Plug>InsertComment <ESC>:call INSERT_MY_COMMENT
inoremap <C-A> <Plug>InsertComment
```

in to vim's command line, just to make sure the configurations have not accidentally been unset. But still, vim wouldn't accept that as a function, but rather copy the plain text to buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I figured out the problem. We simply shouldn't use `noremap` configuration when dealing with `<Plug>`. Changing the map back to `imap` would work.

Comment: also available for `<C-` + nonliterals. example: `<C-_>` which means `control+backslash`